# Is there any limitation to the count of devices I can deploy my apps to in ios 9 and Xcode 7

Tags: ios

With "Free Provisioning" introduced in iOS9 & Xcode 7, has Apple set any limitation to the devices we can deploy our apps to. Is it any way different to the earlier $300(or something) enterprise provisioning profile, except that this one is for free?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limit for everyone except members of the enterprise program, which is a bit different. The limit is 100 of each device: 100 Apple TVs, 100 Apple Watches, 100 iPads, 100 iPhones and 100 iPod Touches.

When you go to [your device list](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action) it will tell you how many devices you have registered so far and how many you have left to register. You should try to prune your list every so often, because the numbers reset when your account renews.

Comment: I haven't looked closely since the changes, but are you sure that iPhones and iPads are counted separately? That did not used to be the case.

Comment: @DuncanC: My reading of [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/programs/whats-included/) suggests they are definitely separate.